# How to see amount of reusable space for a table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I had a huge table(about 300mil rows). After massive DELETE and VACCUUM table files have stopped to grow. That's exactly what I expected. But is there any way to see how much space became reusable?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check out pg_freespacemap module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/pgfreespacemap.html